# ffmpeg convert image to mpeg/mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, images, mp4, jpeg, png

To convert jpg to avi  this code works perfect on my server

```
shell_exec("ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/10 -i image.png out.avi");
```

I need to convert jpg/png images to mp4/mpeg.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i img.png -t 1 out.mp4
```

This will create 1 second video. If you need longer increase the 'loop' value.

Comment: I think you meant to say, "...increase the `-t` value". The `-f image2` is superfluous when using a standard input file name. The H.264 output from your example will not be playable in non-FFmpeg based players unless you add `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.